# MVC 3 custom routes - Redirects, Action, ActionLink have incorrect url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a certain folder structure I have to follow  (/countrycode/language/) so I have my routes set up like below

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "en-us",
    "us/en/{action}/{id}",
    new { Controller = "XXX", action = "Index", cc = "us", ll = "en", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "fr-fr",
    "fr/fr/{action}/{id}",
    new { Controller = "XXX", action = "Index", cc = "fr", ll = "fr", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "de-de",
    "de/de/{action}/{id}",
    new { Controller = "XXX", action = "Index", cc = "de", ll = "de", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I've a single controller and multiple actions in that controller. When I try to redirect to an action, or link to an action within a view, the URL always starts with /us/en/ even if I was currently in /fr/fr/.

e.g. If the current route is /fr/fr/

```
@Html.ActionLink("fooText", "fooAction")
@Url.Action("barAction")
return RedirectToRoute("Index");
```

All end up as

```
/us/en/fooAction
/us/en/barAction
/us/en/
```

How can I make these methods link to the correct URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK instead of:

```
@Html.ActionLink("fooText", "fooAction")
```

I need to use:

```
@Html.RouteLink("fooText", "fr-fr", new { controller = "XXX", action = "fooAction" })
```